# git push not working after deleting keychain on OS X

Tags: git, github, osx-yosemite, keychain

I was having an issue with my keychain earlier today, wherein I was getting endless login prompts that were unresolvable. I deleted the keychain by following the strategy here: http://www.techarp.com/showarticle.aspx?artno=801

Now, however, my git functionality has been impacted. Whenever I try to push to my own repo, I get the following error:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/myusername/myrepo.git/'
```

I tried generating a new SSH key and resetting the authentication. I am able to successfully authenticate when running `ssh -T git@github.com`.

I know this issue has something to do with the keychain. The terminal hangs whenever I try to run the following command:

```
$ git credential-osxkeychain get
```

Where do I go from here? I'm not sure how to troubleshoot or fix this issue. For reference, I am on OS X Yosemite.

Comment: try removing the `credential.helper` from your `~/.gitconfig`.

Comment: what version of git are you using? `git --version` if it's old, that could also be a problem

Comment: Thanks @MikeD! I simply commented out that part of my .gitconfig file, and when I called `git push` again it prompted me for my username/password before successfully pushing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @MikeD's suggestion in the comments, I removed credential.helper from my ~/.gitconfig file. Then, when I called `git push`, it prompted me for my github login credentials before successfully pushing.